# File not found error while try to generate map

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, render, file-not-found

```
 map = folium.Map(location=[points[0]["latitude"], points[0]["longitude"]], zoom_start=12)
        folium.Marker([points[0]["latitude"], points[0]["longitude"]], popup='<i>Start</i>', color='green', fill_color='green').add_to(map)
        # End point marker
        folium.Marker([points[-1]["latitude"], points[-1]["longitude"]], popup='<i>End</i>', color='red', fill_color='red').add_to(map)
        # Route
        folium.PolyLine(locations=[[p["latitude"], p["longitude"]] for p in points], color="blue", weight=2.5, opacity=1).add_to(map)
        map_html = map.get_root().render()
        map_path = 'static/maps/route_map.html'
        with open(map_path, 'w') as file:
            file.write(map_html)
```

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'static/maps/route_map.html' How to fix it?

```
 return render_template("home.html", user=current_user, routes=routes, map_path=map_path)
```

This is the render template

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are using relative path.

`with open(map_path, 'w') as file`;

`open()` thinks that `route_map.html` file is in your current working directory.

To get the files in current working directory you can do:

```
import os
cwd = os.getcwd()        # current working directory 
files = os.listdir(cwd)  # files in that directory
print("Files in %r: %s" % (cwd, files))
```

Rather you can use absolute path :

```
with open('C:\folder\folder\folder\route_map.html', 'w') as file:
    file.write(map_html)
```